# How can I set a sequence of forms?

Tags: inno-setup

I have some forms created in Inno Setup. I need to change a sequence of my forms. How can I do it ?

**EDIT:** here is an example of my code.

```
 [Code]
    var
      UserPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
      UsagePage: TInputOptionWizardPage;
      TrialPage: TOutputMsgWizardPage;
      KeyPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin                                                                                                                           
      { Create the pages }
  UserPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
    'BlaBla', 'BlaBla',  'BlaBla');
  UserPage.Add('Name:', False);
  UserPage.Add('Passward:', False);
  UserPage.Add('Domain ip:', False);

  UsagePage := CreateInputOptionPage(UserPage.ID,
    'BlaBla', 'BlaBla','BlaBla',
    True, False);
  UsagePage.Add('BlaBla1');
  UsagePage.Add('BlaBla2');
  UsagePage.Add('BlaBla3');
  UsagePage.Add('BlaBla4');

  TrialPage := CreateOutputMsgPage(UsagePage.ID,
    'BlaBla', 'BlaBla',  'BlaBla');

  KeyPage := CreateInputQueryPage(UsagePage.ID,
    'BlaBla', 'BlaBla', 'BlaBla');
  KeyPage.Add('Registration key:', False);
end
```

Comment: How about the actual code to create the pages? that's what needs to be changed.

Comment: I have pasted a sample of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the ID you pass to the `After` parameter of the create function. These can be the IDs of other custom pages if required.
Your code will show the welcome page, user page, usage page, key, memo page, then carry on with the rest of the pages.

To change the order of, say the trial and Key Page, you just create them in the other order passing the ID of the previous page:

```
TrialPage := CreateOutputMsgPage(UsagePage.ID,
  'BlaBla', 'BlaBla',  'BlaBla');

KeyPage := CreateInputQueryPage(TrialPage.ID,
  'BlaBla', 'BlaBla', 'BlaBla');
KeyPage.Add('Registration key:', False);
```

Comment: No, it's a change to your current code. If you provide a sample of your code, I can update it.